# Can an AsyncSubject handle the SingleLiveEvent case in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

## Problem

The issue with reactive programming patterns for one-time events is that they may be re-emitted to the subscriber after the initial one-time event has occurred.

For LiveData [the SingleLiveEvent](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) provides a solution using an [`EventObserver`](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9) which may also be applied to Kotlin Flow.

## Question

Can an [`AsyncSubject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) observable be created to handle the case of the SingleLiveEvent in RxJava? The main issue seems to be if there a way for an AsyncSubject to be manually "re-opened" to re-emit data after `onComplete` is called?

## Potential solution

`AsyncSubject` seems like a potential solution for RxJava, without creating an `EventObserver`, as the [documentation](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#AsyncSubject) states that it will *only publish it when the sequence is completed*.

### Implementation - Loading status sample

A loading boolean is emitted from the ViewModel method `initFeed` and view effect state to the view, a fragment in this case. The loading boolean works as expected on the initialization of the fragment and ViewModel sending `true` via `onNext`, and completing with `onComplete` on either a successful or erroneous attempt.

However, the attempt to re-emit a value fails when for example a swipe to refresh initiates the same `initFeed` method. It seems that `onNext` cannot be used after `onComplete` is called for the same object.

*SomeViewEffect.kt*

```
data class _FeedViewEffect(
    val _isLoading: AsyncSubject<Boolean> = AsyncSubject.create(),
)

data class FeedViewEffect(private val _viewEffect: _FeedViewEffect) {
    val isLoading: AsyncSubject<Boolean> = _viewEffect._isLoading
}
```

*SomeViewModel.kt*

```
private fun initFeed(toRetry: Boolean) {
        val disposable = feedRepository.initFeed(pagedListBoundaryCallback(toRetry))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { results ->
                when (results.status) {
                    LOADING -> {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "initFeed ${LOADING.name}")
                        _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(true)
                    }
                    SUCCESS -> {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "initFeed ${SUCCESS.name}")
                        _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(false)
                        _viewEffect._isLoading.onComplete()
                        _viewState._feed.onNext(results.data)
                    }
                    ERROR -> {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "initFeed ${ERROR.name}")
                        _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(false)
                        _viewEffect._isLoading.onComplete()
                        _viewEffect._isError.onNext(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        disposables.add(disposable)
    }
```

*SomeFragment.kt*

```
private fun initViewEffects() {
        val isLoadingDisposable = viewModel.viewEffect.isLoading
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error loading isLoading") }
            .subscribe { isLoading ->
                if (isLoading) progressBar.visibility = VISIBLE
                else {
                    progressBar.visibility = GONE
                    swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        compositeDisposable.addAll(isLoadingDisposable, isErrorDisposable)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use an Event Wrapper

An `AsyncSubject` does not seem to be a suitable solution to handle one-time occurrence emissions from an Observable to a Subscriber. After `onComplete` is called an AsyncSubject can not "re-open" to emit future one-time events.

Using an event wrapper such as an [`Event`](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af#file-event-kt), as outlined in [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) is the best approach.

*FeedViewEffect.kt*

```
data class _FeedViewEffect(
    val _isLoading: BehaviorSubject<Event<Boolean>> = BehaviorSubject.create()
)

data class FeedViewEffect(private val _viewEffect: _FeedViewEffect) {
    val isLoading: BehaviorSubject<Event<Boolean>> = _viewEffect._isLoading
}
```

*FeedViewModel.kt*

```
private fun initFeed(toRetry: Boolean) {
        val disposable = feedRepository.initFeed(pagedListBoundaryCallback(toRetry))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { results ->
                when (results.status) {
                    LOADING -> _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(Event(true))
                    SUCCESS -> _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(Event(false))
                    ERROR -> _viewEffect._isLoading.onNext(Event(false))
                }
            }
        disposables.add(disposable)
    }
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private fun initViewEffects() {
        val isLoadingDisposable = viewModel.viewEffect.isLoading
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error loading isLoading") }
            .subscribe { isLoading ->
                if (isLoading.getContentIfNotHandled() == true) {
                    progressBar.visibility = VISIBLE
                } else {
                    progressBar.visibility = GONE
                    swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        compositeDisposable.addAll(isLoadingDisposable)
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear why you need AsyncSubject which emits only last event. Did you try to use [Behavior](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/BehaviorProcessor.html) or [Publish](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/PublishProcessor.html) Processor for this situation?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and question. Behavior and Publish subject work well in the use case of a view state that is receiving potentially multiple updates. For instance, a feed of content that will be updated frequently.

Comment: However, for a one-time occurrence, such as an error, it is important that future observers do not also observe this error after it has been emitted/handled. This is the use case for the [the SingleLiveEvent](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150), to ensure the occurrence is emitted once using an event wrapper solution like this [EventWrapper](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9).

Comment: You still may try to use BehaviorProcessor but instead of Boolean use optional wrapper. When value is handled emit Optional.empty() and ignore such value in subscribers